# How to change icon when clicked and stay unchanged until clicked again by user in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener

I am currently creating an app that has a  music in android studio. So I created a music icon on the settings menu and when it is clicked it should mute or remove the music. So here is the problem, when I click the music icon it changes to the muted music icon however when I leave the settings menu and go to the settings menu again, the supposedly muted icon returns to the normal music icon.  I don't know why it changes back to its original icon. It is supposed to be muted and when the user clicks on it again then it should be unmuted. I am new to android development so I still don't know this kind of stuff.

Here is my code for the music and sound settings:

```
 public void showSettings(View v){
    TextView exitTxt;
    LinearLayout music,sound;
    Button quitBtn;
    ImageView soundIC, musicIC;
    settingsMenu.setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    settingsMenu.setCancelable(false);
    exitTxt = settingsMenu.findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
    music = settingsMenu.findViewById(R.id.music);
    sound = settingsMenu.findViewById(R.id.sound);
    soundIC = settingsMenu.findViewById(R.id.soundOnIC);
    musicIC = settingsMenu.findViewById(R.id.musicOnIC);

    exitTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            settingsMenu.dismiss();
        }
    });
    music.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean isClicked = false;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isClicked) {
                musicIC.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_music_off);
                music.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline_clicked);
                isClicked = true;
            }
            else{
                music.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline);
                musicIC.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_music);
                isClicked = false;
            }
        }
    });
    sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean isClicked;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isClicked) {
                soundIC.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sound_off);
                isClicked = true;
            }
            else{
                soundIC.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sound);
                isClicked = false;
            }
        }
    });
    settingsMenu.show();
}
```

Comment: Should the state be remembered between the restarts of the app ?

Comment: @trixo yes. Just like on other apps if you disabled the music then it should ne disabled until you enabled it. But for my case when I exit or close the settings menu on my app, all the settings are reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to save the settings information somewhere.

Easy way is just to use Shared Preferences, This is my code that i use

```
public class Preferences {
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    public Preferences(Context context){
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public void StorePreference(String Field,String Value){
        if(preferences!=null){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            if(editor!=null){
                editor.putString(Field,Value);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    }

    public String ReadPreference(String Field){
        String returnData=null;
        if(preferences!=null){
            returnData=preferences.getString(Field,"");
        }
        return returnData;
    }

    public boolean ExistsPreference(String Field){
        boolean returnData=false;
        if(preferences!=null){
            returnData=preferences.contains(Field);
        }
        return returnData;
    }
}
```

Add Preferences as a static to the file which extends Application.

Then to save the data use Preferences.StorePreference(Name of your field,Value).

To read from preferences use Preferences.ReadPreference(Name of your field).

For other methods on how to save data you can look here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#pref